# Why c# regular expression is not working for this case?

Tags: c#, regex

Here is my regular expression

```
\s[a-z]+(\s|$)
```

**input : `a b c`**

**output : `b`**

why it is not detecting "c",although it has space behind it and end on end of line

Comment: but it has space on previous location and end with end of line

Comment: it's not detecting c because of overlapping of matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=\s)([a-z]+)(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.You regex `\s[a-z]+(\s|$)` will not work as you eat up `\s`.so `c` cannot be matched because the `\s` before it has already been eaten by `b`.Use `0 width assertions` instead.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/20